# jquery dialog close on asp.net button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, dialog, onclick

i have a aspx page called A which is using a master page. Page A has a link button, on link button click i want to open a jquery dialog loading with aspx called B. this works fine for me. I have  a asp.net cancel button o`enter code here`n page B, on cancel button click i want to close the jquery dialog and stay on page A. in my code the jquery dialog is getting closed but it reloads the page B in the browser.

Master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="jQueryTest.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mydiv = $("#dialog").dialog({   
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 700,
            width: 900,
            modal: true            
        });        
        mydiv.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form")); 


        });

        function showPanel(){
        var mydiv = $("#dialog")
        // Load the content using AJAX
        mydiv.load('/WebForm1.aspx');
        // Open the dialog        
        mydiv.dialog('open');

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx(page A)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"
    Inherits="jQueryTest._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="contect1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkChangePwd" Text="Click" OnClientClick="showPanel();return false;"
            runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog" style="width: 60%; height: 45%" title="Change password">
    </div>   

</asp:Content>
```

webform1.aspx(Page B)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready($(function () {
     $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").bind("click", function (event) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");    

});

}));

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        this is webform 1
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this has worked for me...

Page that displays the dialog...

```
<html>
<head>
    ...link js files here...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="deleteDialog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page that is the contents of the dialog...

```
<html>
<head>
    ...link js files here...
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Close" id="uxCloseDialog" />
</body>
</html>
```

jquery to show and close the dialog...

```
var deleteDialog;

deleteDialog = $("#deleteDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: "auto",
    modal: true
});

$(".button-delete-24").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    deleteDialog.empty();
    deleteDialog.load("/myDialogPage.aspx"
        , function () {
            $("#uxCloseDialog").click(function () {
                deleteDialog.dialog("close");
                return false;
            });
        });
    deleteDialog.dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

I do use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) so I am not sure if there is extra functionality available to me or not.

Comment: the dialog gets closed , but it still reloads the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.parent:

```
window.parent.jQuery("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

Comment: the dialog gets closed , but it still reloads the same page.